# Highlight or flag data in one workbook which matches data in a separate workbook flagged by a secondary column

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I am looking for a better way to automate a timely task I must do every time I receive a group of files from a client. I am also using Excel 2003.

Is there a way to highlight data in a column of alphanumeric data which match the same data in a separate workbook which are flagged by a secondary column?

Example

Workbook 1, Cell A1, 300
Workbook 2, Cell A1, 300
Workbook 2, Cell B1, Early (Early is the flag)

```vb
(Sheet 1 Account (Column C)) = (Sheet 2 Account (Column A) + Account Flag (Column C))
```

I understand I can sort out the data in Sheet 2, but when I sort the data the data does not correspond in the same order it would be in Sheet 1. I have tried `VLOOKUP` and `IF`, but I can't seem to get them to work correctly. I am also finding Conditional Formatting is not working correctly when referencing external sources.

Comment: vlookup + conditional formatting I beleive will do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Excel 2007 but I believe should apply to Excel 2003:

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A1,[book2]Sheet1!A:A,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A1,[book2]Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)="early"),"FLAG","")
```

[image: SO18748886 example]

For earlier versions of Excel you are correct that conditional formatting will not span books but having set a flag this can be used for CF within the sheet.

By the way, I have included a couple of few extra examples because the VLOOKUP will find only the first instance, so though 400 is flagged Early it is does not show FLAG.

Comment: I think your formula might work I might be missing something.

Comment: Can I use the formula in condition formatting? Just to make it clear the data will be workbook 1 and Workbook 2. There will a be a secondary colomn with entries marke "EARLY*" (More follows the *, but used EARLY to simplify).